# Is there a limit of how close a runway can be to the water?

Tags: faa-regulations, runways, easa-regulations, casa-regulations, dgca-india-regulations

Somtimes planes can either [come up short](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion_Air_Flight_904) or [overrun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_Airlines_Flight_605) a runway, ending up in the water.

Is there some limit for how close a runway can be to the water? Does it factor into the runway safety area that is required to be clear of obstacles (i.e., is water an obstacle)? Is there any requirement for displaced thresholds near water?

I am asking primarily about the US, but information about any other jurisdictions is welcome.

Comment: If SFO is any indication, it can be awful close: http://www.richp.com/pics/aerial-05-20-01/sfo1.jpg

Comment: Check out KCOI: https://img.airnav.com/ap/01869.jpg?v=JFCCQ4 -- a small GA airport for sure, but certainly close to water.

Comment: Doesn't get any closer to water than London City (LCY)

Comment: [Boston Logan](http://goo.gl/maps/7UVBP) and, to a lesser extent, [JFK](http://goo.gl/maps/88Ige) are also very close. Outside the US, [London City](http://goo.gl/maps/0TqPu) and [Hong Kong](http://goo.gl/maps/Aob1I) come to mind.

Comment: @greener Beat me to LCY by four seconds! :-) But there are plenty closer than LCY. The overrun (is that the right word?) at the south-east end of 15R at Boston Logan is built out over Boston Harbour, for example.

Comment: @DavidRicherby [Genoa](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Genoa+Cristoforo+Colombo+Airport), [Tokyo Haneda](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Genoa+Cristoforo+Colombo+Airport), [Lampedusa](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Lampedusa+Airport/)(?) and [Gibraltar](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Gibraltar+International+Airport/) as well

Comment: Sydney (SYD) can be also a [good example](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/32/A%C3%A9roport_Sydney.jpg).

Comment: OK, so are there actually any airports that *aren't* right next to water? ;-)

Comment: In addition to JFK, consider LaGuardia -- which is also close to the water vertically; major storms have sometimes put the runway under water and shut down the airport. (I had a flight cancelled for that reason once.) And I seem to remember that JFK can handle seaplanes.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Yes, there are. On [some](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/RK_0602_00811_LuklaAnflug.jpg) of them overrun would be much worse than on the near-water ones. And often there is [some water anyway](http://www.le-mckernan.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/DSC_0427-1024x680.jpg)

Comment: [Saba's runway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juancho_E._Yrausquin_Airport) is both very short (396m) and surrounded by water and cliffs.

Comment: Let's raise the bar a bit: the runway of [Madeira Airport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madeira_Airport) is **above** water.

Comment: Don't forget Kansai in Japan, it is surrounded by water on all sides and built on an artificial island.  Overruns, short landings or loss of directional control (to one side) will put you in the water.

Comment: Check out Logan (Boston) [Google Maps 42.363300,-71.008250]
Every runway at this major hub has at least one end in the water.

Comment: Isn't there some _beach_ (in Scandinavia?) where scheduled flights take off and land (only at low tide)?

Comment: [Barra Airport, Scotland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barra_Airport_%28Scotland%29) the runway is on the beach.

Comment: @keshlam - it was LGA that was originally a flying boat (not seaplane) base, and the still-in-use Marine Air Terminal is a reminder of those years https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_314_Clipper

Comment: Could swear that I've gone past a marine air terminal at JFK, when getting lost in the parking lots... but I certainly could be misremembering.

Comment: Of course sometime the water IS the runaway ...

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Not just the overrun.  Almost all of Logan is on top of what used to be harbour.  (Which is why part of eastern Logan is actually in Winthrop rather than Boston; the water boundary between the two was drawn long before the Logan landfilling, and part of the land reclaimed for the airport ended up lying east of that boundary, and, hence, being part of Winthrop.)

Comment: @ANeves: Aren't parts of both runways at la Guardia also built out above the water?

Comment: yet another one: [Wellington Airport](https://www.google.com/maps/search/wellington+airport/@-41.324944,174.8018366,2764m/data=!3m1!1e3) is very close to water at both ends. It looks like the southern end was extended over the road (creating a tunnel) to add some safety area.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

FAA Advisory Circular (AC) [150/5300-13A](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/150_5300_13A.pdf) covers "standards and recommendations for airport design." It does not include any restrictions on proximity to bodies of water, but it does make the following *recommendation* in paragraph 319(a):

> It is recommended that the entire RSA and RPZ be accessible to rescue and fire-fighting vehicles such that no part of the RSA or RPZ is more than 330 feet (100 m) from either an all-weather road or a paved operational surface. Where an airport is adjacent to a body of water where access by rescue personnel from airport property is desirable, it is recommended that boat launch ramps with appropriate access roads be provided.

The actual FARs ([14 CFR 139, Certification and Operations: Land Airports](http://www.faa.gov/airports/airport_safety/part139_cert/)) also do not state a limit. The only reference to bodies of water of any kind is in §139.325 (Airport emergency plan) paragraph (e):

> The plan required by this section
>   shall contain provisions, to the extent
>   practicable, for the rescue of aircraft
>   accident victims from significant bodies
>   of water or marsh lands adjacent to
>   the airport which are crossed by the
>   approach and departure flight paths of
>   air carriers. A body of water or marsh
>   land is significant if the area exceeds
>   one-quarter square mile and cannot be
>   traversed by conventional land rescue
>   vehicles. To the extent practicable, the
>   plan shall provide for rescue vehicles
>   with a combined capacity for handling
>   the maximum number of persons that
>   can be carried on board the largest air
>   carrier aircraft that the airport reasonably
>   can be expected to serve.

So, bottom line: there is no limit, but airports are required to take water into due consideration when developing emergency plans, and the FAA looks at each airport and plan on a case-by-case basis during airport certification.

As for the rest of the world, I have no authoritative information; but as others have posted, it certainly seems like the situation is the same, there being numerous examples of airports worldwide built on natural or reclaimed land *very* close to water.

Answer (score 12):

There is no such limit indeed. [Princess Juliana International Airport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_Juliana_International_Airport) in Sint Maarten is possibly the most iconic example of airport located near a water body, because of the beach over which airliners fly when approaching RWY 09. As other mentioned, they are numerous other examples of airports that may be even closer to a water body (i.e. without a beach in between).

[image]
*[image source](http://www.captmondo.com/?p=1878)*

Comment: What is so close to the water is not the runway, but a blastpad. The runway at Saint Marteen airport is almost 190m inland.

Answer (score 8):

Water is not an obstacle. There are plenty of examples around the world where runways are built on purpose-reclaimed land and the ocean starts just a handful of meters from the end of the runway.

For some random examples, check Nice-Côte d'Azur or Gibraltar or St. Maarten.

Comment: ...Or [La Guardia](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WJegv.png)

Answer (score 5):

[Runway 28L and 28R at KSFO](http://aviationtroubleshooting.blogspot.ca/2013/07/visual-approach-do-not-abandon-visual.html), as well as 19L and 19R, have their thresholds right next to the San Francisco Bay.

If you recall, in July 2013, [Asiana Airlines Flight 214](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asiana_Airlines_Flight_214) landed short due to pilot error.

In November 1968, [Japan Airlines Flight 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan_Airlines_Flight_2) completely missed the runway and landed in San Francisco Bay.

Answer (score 4):

Not going by Barra Airport -

> Barra Airport is famous for its beauty - boasting beaches, machair and hills - and all in a small island; Barra is a special place to visit - especially memorable if you fly in because of the beach landing strip. Washed by the tide twice a day, **Traigh Mhor beach is reputed to be the only beach runway in the world to handle scheduled airline services**.

- See [Barra Airport website](http://www.hial.co.uk/barra-airport/airport-information/) 
  [image]

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the runway at Barra is also popular with cockle pickers; they have to keep an eye on the windsock to see if planes might be landing.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the question is yes, there are limits. I'll expand for ICAO regulated airports, but this is also true for FAA ones.

ICAO defines an area surrounding a runway, called runway strip, which purpose is to:

```
a) to reduce the risk of damage to aircraft running off a runway; and
b) to protect aircraft flying over it during take-off or landing operations.
```

A water runway strip would not reduce the risk of damage to aircraft running off a runway. It would in fact increase it, so a runway strip cannot be made of water.

The size of the runway strip depends on the type of runway, but it ranges 150 m to 0m (zero)  in width, and it must extend 30 to 60 m beyond each end of the runway (or the end of the stopways, if there are any).

So, the runway strip contains at least the runway (and its stopways) and extends beyond it on its ends, and sometimes (depending on the type of runway) it also extends to the sides of the runway, and it defines the limits to how close a runway can be to water.

Going even further, ICAO defines a Runway End Safety Area (RESA) for some types of runways which further increases the minimum distance of water to the runway.

Airports such as Sint Marteen, where the runway is almost 190m from the water, are just examples of how the runway strip and the RESA are applied as safety measures against aircraft running off a runway.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is Albert Whitted Airport](https://www.google.com/maps/@27.7630431,-82.6250911,1582m/data=!3m1!1e3), a GA facility in St. Petersburg, FL, which has actually juts out into Tampa Bay.